# CNContactViewController does not span the full width

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, cncontactviewcontroller

I use a `CNContactViewController` in a `NSTabViewController` as well as a `NSPopover`. In both cases the ViewController has a size that is too small (See red color in Screenshot).

The other tabs use all available space, like one would expect.

[image]

I tried to set the frame of the ViewController upon `viewWillAppear` but this is ignored:

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    for i in tabViewItems{
        if let vc = i.viewController as? CNContactViewController{
            vc.contact = CNContact.dummyContact()
            vc.view.frame = view.frame
            vc.view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
            view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.green.cgColor
        }
    }
}
```

In a popover the height is the same:

[image: same-problem]

#### Update

I do get this error when launching the app, however, I don't have access to the constraints on `ABRemotePersonView`, so I am at a loss.

> [133:9106090] [Layout] Detected missing constraints for `<ABRemotePersonView: 0x6080001411e0>`.  It cannot be placed because there are not enough constraints to fully define the size and origin. Add the missing constraints, or set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=YES` and constraints will be generated for you. If this view is laid out manually on **macOS 10.12** and later, you may choose to not call `[super layout]` from your override. Set a breakpoint on `DETECTED_MISSING_CONSTRAINTS` to debug. This error will only be logged once.

Comment: Sound more like bug in internal implementation (bugreport.apple.com). I would try to play with lldb and subviews to get the instance of ABRemotePersonView and set the frame size manually. (Production -> always test respondsToSelector ...)

Comment: Second suggestion, try to move the code to viewDidLoad. 2 years back I asked similar question here. TSI confirmed bug.